# Strange behavior when creating a jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, magnolia

I have a jar which was created with maven (mvn package). When I put it in the magnolia WEB-INF/lib folder magnolia tries to install it.

But when I open the jar with an unarchiver, compress the folder to a zip, change the extension to .jar and then put it back in WEB-INF/lib magnolia ignores it.

Shouldn't those two jars be exactly the same or am I missing something?

**Edit**

Because some of you didn't get my question here's what my real problem is:

I have to build a magnolia module programmatically and fill it with some components which the user added on a website. I have a temporary folder on my server where I build the module folder structure. Then I compress this folder structure to a jar and the user downloads it.

Then the user can put that jar in the webapps/magnoliaAuthor/WEB-INF/lib folder to install the module. But it doesn't work because magnolia ignores it.

After experimenting I found that magnolia also ignores modules after doing what I explained in my question above.

I think that this may has to do something with why magnolia won't install my module.

Comment: well, are they? Did you compare the contents?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question but I'm scared by the fact that you're copying files by hand in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Try to explain your problem better

Comment: Maybe your zip-tool uses another compression-algorithm than the default maven-package-plugin. Maybe on unzipping you modified line-endings of .class files (or something else). You should compare both file-trees using a diff-tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org) first.

Comment: @Gimby yes they are the same

Comment: So how do you "compress the folder structure" ?

Comment: Which magnolia version are you using ? You might need to set magnolia.debug property to true, if you would like any jars to be processed in runtime.

Comment: @Ducaz035 magnolia 5.4.5 and I don't want to process the jar at runtime

Comment: @Gimby I just found out that they aren't exactly the same: I made the content visible in the terminal without unarchiving the jar and saw that the manifest isn't the first entry whereas in the working jars it is. I'm going to try if changing this will solve my problem.

Comment: @Dalibor I don't really know what "first entry" means. There isn't really any set order, the file should have the path META-INF/manifest.mf inside the zip/jar.

Comment: @Gimby You are right, there isn't really any set order but the manifest often has to be the first one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)
I assume that this causes my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:

In a working module jar the manifest is the first entry. But after unarchiving the entries get mixed up and that's why after archiving the manifest isn't the first entry anymore.

Magnolia ignores jars that don't have the manifest as the first entry.